# Union of heaven, earth and nether regions

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, krishna, swarga

While reading Mahabharata, I came across following verse over [here](https://www.mahabharataonline.com/translation/mahabharata_13a025.php)

> That part where Bhagirathi-Ganga flows in a northward direction is
> known as the union of heaven, earth, and the nether regions.

They have not mentioned the actual place where this happens. Does this verse have any reference in other hindu scriptures?